# Git Sourcetree versioning system

Tags: git, version-control

I have two repositorys on my Pc for exercise purposes, because I am new to git and versioning systems.
Can please someone explain why I am getting  <<< HEAD and >>> the large number after I do a merge with the files on my local repository?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are annotations added to the code when a merge encounters a conflict.  It's gits way of telling you the 2 pieces of text that conflicted.  In this case the text between `HEAD` and `===` is the text in the current branch.  The text between `===`and `>>>>` is the code in the branch which is being merged.  The long number at the end is simply the SHA1 value of the item being merged here.  You can view it in its entirety by issuing the following command

```
git show ec48e6ac
```

Comment: @patentul yes, it's up to you to fix this merge by picking the correct value for the conflict.  Once you've picked it simply delete the `<<<`  and `>>>>` lines and everything in between.  In its place paste in the manually merged code